# Firebase custom notifications with FlutterFire

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Thanks to Firebase and FlutterFire, it's easy to send regular notifications from the servers to the users' devices. Those notifications include a title, a body, and an image url. But what about creating a no-that-simple notification, like Telegram's or WhatsApp's?

The simple question is to avoid sending a `Notification` from the server, and instead set the `data` field to the push message. But according to [the FlutterFire documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage):

> Data only messages are considered low priority by devices when your application is in the background or terminated, and will be ignored

So, it sounds like if we want to have a reliable delivery system, we should add a `Notification` to our push messages. But that notification is so simple. And, again, according to [the documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#notifications):

> If your message is a notification one (includes a notification property), the Firebase SDKs will intercept this and display a visible notification to your users (assuming you have requested permission & the user has notifications enabled)

So: If I want a reliable system, I have to send `Notifications`, but I do it, I can't tell FlutterFire to use my custom notifications.

So the question is: how to show custom notifications with FlutterFire?

What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image: The WhatsApp new message notifications]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to try setting the priority of the push notification.

```
You can however explicitly increase the priority by sending additional properties on the FCM payload:

On Android, set the priority field to high.
On Apple (iOS & macOS), set the content-available field to true.
```

On the server side code, it looks like:

```kotlin
message.setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder().setPriority(AndroidConfig.Priority.HIGH).build());
message.setApnsConfig(ApnsConfig.builder().setAps(Aps.builder().setContentAvailable(true).build()).build());
```

Comment: It seems it works, at least on Android. Hope I say something here when testing the iOS version.